# How to turn off the padding of page-content-wrapper in Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a web using Bootstrap 3 and I'm using the page-content-wrapper script. When I collapse the page, logo of my web(left right corner in navbar) changes the position due to the padding that the script creates. How can I solve this and have a fixed logo in my navbar?

Comment: you can use `position: fixed` in your logo css, or you could remove the padding with `padding: 0 !important` in a custom css. I would go with the 1st one

Answer (score 0):

You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

```
#yourlogoId
{
    position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it already but the script probably overwrites it and it still doesn't work

Comment: can you share the code of the script?